# In my Application under test when I run a script a random dialog Box appears and then vanishes instantly. However it causes my code to fail

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

In my Application under test when I run a script using Selenium Webdriver (Java) a random dialog Box appears and then vanishes instantly. However it causes my code to fail.

On checking the console I see `UnhandledAlertException`

I have tried using the following code under a try catch block:

```
Alert alert = webdriver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

However to this exception occurs as: `NoAlertPresentException`. Of course it will appear as the dialog box vanishes instantly. Due to this issue my previously well working codes are failing.

IE Driver : 2.41
Selenium version : 2.37

Comment: You really should match your IE Driver version to your Selenium version.

Comment: Please could tell me which Compatible IE driver with the selenium version : 2.37

Comment: And if I have to use an older version of IE driver from where should I get it

Comment: [Internet Explorer Driver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) for `Selenium`.

Comment: It is better if you can use updated version of selenium version instead of using old version. Try the same.

If still problem persist, provide the screenshot of the page with alert box.